# Return a dynamic response in Mock-server

Tags: json, mocking, postman, mockserver

I am working with https://www.mock-server.com/ and I've set my expectations in JSON format. I would like to fetch a field from request body and send it in the response body. This can be done in Postman as following : `{{$body 'id' }}`, but I don't find a way to do it in mock-server.
Do you have any ideas?

Tried the following value to fetch the field `{{$body 'id' }}`

Comment: Which language using it (examples python or node.js)?

Comment: Just running the Mock-server container and then sending expectations in JSON format I don't use language to interact with the mock server